# Symfony2 equivalent of before_filter?

Tags: php, symfony

Just wondering if Symfony2 has an equivalent to before_filter from Rails? I want to alter the layout of my application based on the type of user that is viewing it. Thanks a lot.

EDIT: I should clarify my question. I want to alter the layout of my application based on a URL parameter. So ultimately all the before_filter equivalent has to do is make every template rendered by the controller inherit from a different base template based on that URL parameter. I should add I already have over 50 controller actions that render templates so ideally the solution should be something that is easy to enable application-wide without having to edit every controller action.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that function but you can try `{% if is_granted('ROLE_XXX') %}` in twig templates or `$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')` in the controller

You'll find more information in http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Close equivalent would be creating [kernel.view](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-view-event) event listener. You can also take a look at [LiipThemeBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle) to change layout on the fly.

Comment: "This event is called only if the Controller does not return a Response object. The purpose of the event is to allow some other return value to be converted into a Response." I'm not sure if this is what I want. I don't want to convert my template into a Response object, I just want to render from a different base template based on a URL parameter.